# How to define a breakable, resumeable three column list environment

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, page-breaking

How can I obtain the following? It should have some features:

1. List environment is able to break over pages;
2. Each line in list environment has 3 columns. 1st column (counters) is left aligned. 2nd column is right aligned. 3rd column is left aligned.
3. List environment is able to be resumed. in the following file, after 3b. we have some text and after that, we have 4a.
4. We can put a label for every list item (for example `\label{1a}` or `\label{2}`), and anywhere in the body of text, we can refer to this item. For example we put `in \ref{1a}` in the TeX file and we'll have `in 1a`. in the output file.

[image]

Comment: How do you distinguish between regular and sub-enumeration? Your example also shows a drop back to `3a` and `3b`. Why is that?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

`longtable` can help here (updated with sub item numbering and again with numbering tweaked as requested):
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}

\setlength\textheight{10\baselineskip}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand\theenumii{\alph{enumii}}
\makeatletter
\def\subitem{\omit\@arstrut 
\ifnum\value{enumii}=0 \stepcounter{enumi}\fi
\refstepcounter{enumii}\theenumi\theenumii\hfill}
\def\item{\omit\setcounter{enumii}{0}\let\omit\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{longtable}{>{\refstepcounter{enumi}\setcounter{enumii}{0}\theenumi}lrl}
& something& something else\\
& foo&bar\\
\label{this}& red&blue\\
& something about \ref{this} & or that\\
& foo&bar\\
\subitem& foo&bar\\
\subitem& foo&bar\\
\item
\subitem& foo&bar\\
\subitem& foo&bar\\
\item
\subitem& foo&bar\\
& foo&bar\\
&a & b\\
&c & d\\
\subitem\label{thissubi}& foo&bar\\
\subitem& foo&bar\\
& foo&bar\\
& foo& ref subitem: \ref{thissubi}\\
& foo&bar\\
& foo&bar\\
& foo&bar
\end{longtable}


some text

\begin{longtable}{>{\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi}lrl}
& something& something else\\
& foo&bar\\
\label{thisb}& red&blue\\
& something about \ref{thisb} & or that\\
& foo&bar\\
\subitem& foo&bar\\
\subitem& foo&bar\\
& foo&bar\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it's not exactly what i want. for example, after list item number 4, we have 5 and after that, 5a. but i want 5a right after 4, not 5. there is another problem: in your example code, we have 5a and 5b. if we want "subitem" in 8th list item, we'll have 8c, 8d, ..., but we should have 8a, 8b. the last problem is referencing. in my computer when i compile your code with MikTeX 2.9, referencing does not work properly.

Comment: You have to put labels in the first column for referencing to work, the other counting issues are easily addressed. Really these things are much easier if the question contains a complete full example document and information about the expected result.

Comment: thanks for update. but how can i refer to rows: "6a, 6b, 10a, ..."?

Comment: when i use four "\subitem" commands, it's output is, for example, "1a, 1b, 1c, 1d", but i need a maximum of two subitems in a row. for example i just want "1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, ...". i never need "c, d, ..." romans, but "a, b" for maximum.

Comment: updated to allow 6a 6b 7a 7b

Comment: thanks. but 2 other problems.
`\begin{longtable}{>{\refstepcounter{enumi}\setcounter{enumii}{0}\theenumi}lr}

\item
\subitem \label{1a}& foo \\subitem \label{1b}& foo \\item
\subitem \label{2a}& foo \\subitem \label{2b}& foo \\item
\subitem \label{3a}& foo \\subitem \label{3a}& foo \\item
\subitem \label{4a}& foo  \\subitem \label{4a}& foooo \\end{longtable}‎

\ref{1a}, 
\ref{1b}, 
\ref{2a}, 
\ref{2b}, 
\ref{3a}, 
\ref{3b}, 
\ref{4a}, 
\ref{4b}`

Comment: That looks like invalid input, you have repeated labels second \label{3a} should be \label{3b} and same for second label 4a

Comment: using `\usepackage[pagebackref=false]{hyperref}`, references refer to improper places. may be my last question ;)

Comment: he same identifier (name{enumii.0}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
too late tonight probably best to ask a new question perhaps someone more familiar with current hyperref and in a different time zone will answer

Comment: ok, thanks for all your efforts to solve my problems :)